# @Valid is not getting invoked if I use @PreAuthorize method level security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Following is a code snippet from my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Constants.REST_CONTROLLER_ENDPOINT)
class ProductRestController {

private final ProductValidator productValidator;
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(productValidator);
}

private Product createProductFromJson(Product input) {
    ...
    return product;
}

@PasswordFilter
@RequestMapping(consumes = { Constants.HAL_CONTENT_TYPE,
       Constants.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResponseEntity<Product> createProduct(@RequestBody @Validated Product input) {
    Product product = createProductFromJson(input);
    Product savedProduct = productRepository.save(product);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(product, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@PasswordFilter
@PreAuthorize("@productRestController.validatePermission(authentication, #product)")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = { Constants.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE }, method = {
        RequestMethod.PUT })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<Product> updateProduct(Principal principal, @PathVariable Long id,
        @RequestBody @Validated Product product) {
       ...
    return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedProduct, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The `@Validated` is not getting invoked in the createProduct method.
If I comment the `@PreAuthorize` the `@Validated` is getting invoked in the createProduct method. The annotation is not even on the createProduct method so I am not sure if this is to do with the `@InitBinder`.

This is a SpringBoot 1.4.1 application. I am using a mockmvc `@SpringBootTest` to test this method

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the `@InitBinder` method needs to be public for the validation to be invoked:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
binder.setValidator(productValidator);
}
```